# Deserializing XML with defined ENTITY to objects using XStream / StaxDriver

Tags: java, xml, xstream, stax

i want to de-serialize the XML file to java/groovy objects using XStream.
XML file has ENTITY defined. So I used the StaxDriver to resolve entities automatically. But StaxDriver/XStream ignore/remove partial contents.

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE parent [
<!ENTITY File_file SYSTEM "File_file.xml">
]>

<parent>
 <name>NAME</name>
 <description>DSCRIPTION</description>
 <context>
     <files>
&File_file;
</files>
 </context>
</parent>
```

After de-serialize and print as XML again: Expected is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
 <name>NAME</name>
 <description>DSCRIPTION</description>
   <context>
      <files>
<file>
    <name>name</name>
    <path>location path</path>
</file>
      </files>
   </context>
</parent>
```

but I see below:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
 <name>NAME</name>
 <description>DSCRIPTION</description>
   <context>
      <files>
<file>
</file>
      </files>
   </context>
</parent>
```

Code/logic to deserialize xml content.

```
    public class Parser {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length != 1) {
        System.out.println("Usage:Parser <Input File>");
        return;
    }
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
    xstream.alias("parent", Parent.class);
    xstream.alias("context", Context.class);
    xstream.alias("files", Files.class);
    xstream.addImplicitCollection(Files.class, "files");
    xstream.alias("files", File.class);
    String xml = Util.getFileText(args[0]);//file.text;
    System.out.println(xml);
    Parent te = (Parent)xstream.fromXML(xml);
    System.out.println(XmlUtil.serialize(xstream.toXML(te)));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Issue was identified as File.class referred in XStream alias() for transformation. Instead of using local com.app.model.File.class, java.io.File.class used which caused the parser/xstream not to transform the tags, eventually removes it.